# Как сохранять установленный аддон Firefox через Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random
import os

directory = '/home/user/ffadns/'
files = os.listdir(directory)
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
def randaddon():
        addon = directory + str(random.choice(files))
        return addon
fp.add_extension(randaddon())
fp.add_extension(randaddon())
fp.add_extension(randaddon())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("http://ya.ru")
```

Все работает отлично аддоны ставятся, но после закрытия браузера их уже нет, то есть они хранятся пока выполняется скрипт. Как сделать, чтобы эти аддоны сохранялись в профили?
При установке аддоны, я так понимаю, прописываются в файлы, что на скрине. Либо есть какое-то решение которое я не вижу, либо нужно в скрипте прописывать необходимую инфу для установленных аддонов. Можно обойтись без

```
add_extension
```

а сразу писать аддоны в профили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создай профиль вручную (когда закрыт браузер, в консоли введи `firefox.exe -p`), установи нужные аддоны, а потом в своем коде подключайся к данному профилю.
По-другому никак.